# On a desktop, is using 'suspend' beneficial?

Tags: 11.10, suspend

I have a desktop with enough RAM and whatever else required to run Unity smoothly. My understanding is that the "suspend" option is usually for laptops.

I used it recently and when booting up, it seemed to take as long - if not longer - than a clean boot.

When and why would I use "suspend" on my desktop? What are the advantages / disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

Suspend usually comes important in laptops when you close the lid.
Its better to hibernate in case of Desktops